# What is causing my my screen to go black?

Tags: 12.04, display, screen, xrandr

I have this Ubuntu (12.04.4) netbook hooked up to a 55" screen to display slides and info. It was running fine for quite a while and was set up not to go to screen saver or anything. I think there was a power outage last night so I came in and pressed the power button to turn it on. Now when I turn the computer on, the screen is black. Here's the state of things...

```
user@computer:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 240, current 320 x 240, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1024x768       60.0 +   60.0
   800x600        60.3     56.2
   640x480        59.9
DVI1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080      60.0 +
   1600x900       60.0
   1440x900       59.9
   1360x768       59.8     60.0
   1280x800       59.8
   1280x720       60.0
   1024x768       60.0
   800x600        60.3
   640x480        60.0
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I SSH in tried to do something like:

```
xrandr --output DVI1 --mode 1920x1080
```

That didn't throw an error but didn't make the screen stop being black. I read that using "--off" might help ( http://www.linuxine.com/story/xrandr-cannot-find-crtc-output-vga1 ) so I did something like this:

```
xrandr --output DVI1 --off
xrandr --output LVDS1 --off
xrandr --output DVI1 --mode 1920x1080
```

That worked! Then I kept sitting there for a few minutes and after maybe 5 or 10 minutes. The screen went black again! What is going on here...? Is there some sort of corruption I can resolve? Why would the screen go black again after it has already been initialized with xrandr?

---

EDIT: I forgot to mention... when I reboot, it shows the BIOS on the monitor. It's only after Ubuntu starts up that it goes black. This is what makes me thing it is a software or configuration problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... This is not looks like a software problem. First (if u are able ofcourse) plug an external monitor and boot ur netbook to see if u got signal. This way we can exclude the possibility of a damaged gpu. If u boot normal with signal in the external monitor then it means that 1) Your inverter is burned (or is about to burn and stops to work when it get warm) and or 2) Is the backlight of ur screen that means u need a new screen but the 2nd is a lil bit rare damage. Many times screen is nearly black and hardly u can see signal under some light, so boot and watch the screen carefully. Also when you boot w8 some mins and see if the hard disk read and if u can listen the ubuntu's entrance sound. To be sure that is only a screen or inverter problem and not something worst. I hope to help u a lil bit. Sry for my english :)

Comment: See my edit: In short, on boot, BIOS displays on the screen fine. It's only after Ubuntu gets started that the screen goes black. This leads me to think it's software or config related.